# Screenshots won't be saved after System language change

Tags: screen-capture, macos

I have changed the language from my MacOS system and now it won't save the screenshots anymore. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: We need bit more information!

Comment: Did you change your keyboard layout ? What system ect...

Comment: Are you taking screenshots using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, cmd+shift+ctrl+[3-4], they won't save on desktop. I changed the language while I had Snow Leopard, and they stopped working, now I have Mountain Lion and the problem continues…

Comment: Please tell what language did you choose? What I am thinking is you keyboard layout is now different.

Comment: Try taking a screen shot using the Grab app in your utility

Comment: I was using english, now I chose german. The Grap app will work, I also have a screenshot plus widget that works. The only issue is the annoying hotkeys that won't save it on the desktop anymore…

Comment: Nevermind, I've just managed to solve this issue. It was annoying me for almost one year and the related made me to think of changing the output location for the screenshots, since the german version changes some folders display names (although it doesn't change the Desktop ones)… Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Language could lead to screen shot not finding the right location to save to.

So I would recommend to change the output, = save location for the keyboard short cut.

There are few ways to do this one of them is in Terminal.

For example, if I want to have the screenshots appear in my Pictures folder, I would use:

> defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/

To have the changes take effect, you then must type:

> killall SystemUIServer

You can change the saved screenshot location back to the default setting by specifying the desktop again:

> defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/

Again, you’d need to kill SystemUIServer for changes to take effect.

Comment: I can't even upvote your comments and your answer… sometimes it's really annoying to have this low points account. Thanks for complementing with a deeper answer.

Comment: Don't worry about up voting, you will gather points fast the way you are proceeding :), there u go just got 10 up for your answer .)

Comment: I usually don't get too many points because I normally find the answer for my questions before I ask them over here. Two more and I can up vote haha xD. But I'll stop with the off-topic… if there were a message system it would be better…

Comment: You can always ask a question and then answer it your self :) If it is a good answer you might get points :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue updating the output folder with the following commands on the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop
killall SystemUIServer
```